# Vertex u is shown in the topological sort right after v, if and only if there is an edge from u to v

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, topological-sort

Prove or disprove: Given directed graph G=(V,E) without circles, and given two vertices u,v in V, the vertex u is shown in the topological sort right after v, iff there is an edge from u to v.

I know that this is not true. My professor wrote those two examples:

1. First example for the => part:

[image]

1. Second example for the <= part:

[image]

Is it possible to example why those examples disprove the statement?

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but it seems like the images themselves give no clear counterexample. If there is any (potentially necessary) information left out, I suggest adding it to the question.

Comment: @ADdV No additional information has left out but I'll try to explain what I understand from the first part: G is DAG and you don't have the (u,v) edge. Also L[v]<L[u]. But why vertex u is shown in the topological sort right after v? Same goes for the second image.